# Use filter on not already loaded elements

Tags: scroll, filter, infinite, ready

I use this script Jquery to show only one category of a list hidden by css:

```
    <script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('span')
  .filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == 'vendu'; })
  .css('display','block');
  });
</script>
```

It works fine for elements already loaded.

Is there a way to apply the script on not already loaded elements?
When the users go down the portfolio page, the next images are loading (infinite scroll)

Perhaps the .on function could do the trick, but i can't make it works

Thank you for your help !
I'm quite new in JQuery so be kind with me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in a function and call the function on each update of your elements

Ex:

```
<script language="javascript">
  function showOnlyOneCategory(){
      $('span')
         .filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == 'vendu'; })
         .css('display','block');
  } 
  $(document).ready(function(){
      showOnlyOneCategory(); // at loading and use it after each update
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your time. It doesnt work, but I'm sure that it's my fault ;)

Comment: There's a PHP file : POST http://www.hutzemakers.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
 when the page is loading more content.

Comment: How do I call the function at this moment?

Comment: Can you add the code in the description of your question please ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I finally find a satisfaisant solution:

```
$(".portfolio-container").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
     $('span')
  .filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == 'vendu'; })
  .css('display','block');
  });
```

It applies my script when something changes in the dom